# How to group multiple columns while replacing zero with values (pandas)?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, replace, group-by

| Name | Cat | Dog | Frog | Pig |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ana | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Ana | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

| Name | Cat | Dog | Frog | Pig |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ana | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I'd like to group these two rows by name and replace the 'zeros' by one when is filled. The output should be like this

Comment: The question is too unclear. It seems like MAX or SUM should be used, but due to this less sample data, it's unknown what of these two is correct (or even both could be wrong). Please provide more meaningful sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `max()`

```
df = df.groupby('Name').max().reset_index()
```

output:

```
> df

  Name  Cat  Dog  Frog  Pig
0  Ana    1    1     1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

what you might want to do here is an aggregation. One way to obtain your desired output is to use the pandas dataframe methods **grouby()** and **sum()**

Here is how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        ('Ana', 0, 1, 0, 0)
,       ('Ana', 1, 0, 1, 0)        
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Pig'])

print(df.groupby(['Name']).sum())
```

Then the **output** would be:

```
      Cat  Dog  Frog  Pig
Name
Ana     1    1     1    0
```

If you want to know more about these methods, you can follow the links below:

**groupby():** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

**sum():** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Comment: This would work only in the case that each group has 2 rows. If there are more than 2 rows, the values could be more than 1 by summation.